# ($x,y,z$ are positive real numbers)

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I need this for lemma but I don't know how to prove it.
Maybe rearrangement inequality or arithmetic-geometric mean inequality would work.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Here is a quick reference for [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which is used on this site for formatting mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 2):

By Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality:

$$\left(x^5+y^2+z^2\right)\left(\frac{1}{x}+y^2+z^2\right)\ge \left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^2$$

$$\Rightarrow \text{L.H.S}=\sum _{cyc}\frac{1}{x^5+y^2+z^2}\le \frac{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}+2\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^2}$$

$$=\frac{\frac{xy+yz+xz}{xyz}+2\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^2}\le \frac{3\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^2}=\frac{3}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\text{R.H.S}$$

Answer (score 1):

The Lev Radzivilovski's proof.

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}-\frac{1}{x^5+y^2+z^2}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^5-x^2}{x^5+y^2+z^2}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2-\frac{1}{x}}{x^2+\frac{y^2+z^2}{x^3}}\geq0.$$
Now, if $x\geq1$ so $$x^2-\frac{1}{x}\geq0$$ and $$x^2+\frac{y^2+z^2}{x^3}\leq x^2+y^2+z^2.$$
If $0<x\leq1$ so  $$x^2-\frac{1}{x}\leq0$$ and $$x^2+\frac{y^2+z^2}{x^3}\geq x^2+y^2+z^2.$$
Thus, 
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2-\frac{1}{x}}{x^2+\frac{y^2+z^2}{x^3}}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2-\frac{1}{x}}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\geq\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\geq0.$$